# How can I export emacs documents in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, emacs, org-mode

When I try to export a document from org-mode in emacs, c-X, c-E now results in 'Can't find library org' whereas in 10.04 it opened the export dialog allowing me to produce html, pdf etc. from the source org file.

Searching with Google, I found [this bug for redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=830162) which looks closely related.

The trouble is I don't know how to get hold of the emacs-el package it talks about in ubuntu in order to try its workaround so I'm currently stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of emacs you are using, you can either install the emacs23-el or emacs24-el package.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs24-el
```

That seems to work around the issue here. There is a similar bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1172214 , so it seems like it may be a bug in emacs24.